# how to cut building into squres in reivit?

Tags: sensors, revit

i'm in a project to place sensor in building(ifc file).

Like the image(in the link below,page5 left) below, I plan to find a parking lot ifc file and put it in revit.
Then cut the roof in to squares,and place sensor into the squares.
I'm totally loss now.I want to ask where could I start and which language should i use?Java or C#?

please help me ,thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!

http://ubi-lab.naist.jp/www_old/papers/DICOMO2010-marc.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be using Revit, then use C# instead of Java. You could also use the [RevitPythonShell](https://code.google.com/p/revitpythonshell/) while you explore the API - you will be doing a lot of exploring!

You should probably start by

- defining your goal properly (exercise: tidy up your question before it gets closed!)
- breaking that down into subtasks
- figuring out what you need to learn to solve each subtask (c# is a very vague notion of what you need to learn)
- hint: go through some tutorials on programming Revit!
- Read Jeremy Tammiks blog "The Building Coder" for fun and profit!

Comment: Thank you! but i'm still confused.